# How to get less than data of selected month of year in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

i have a table where all data of students. i need only less than month data of selected month of year. i have date column data like these.

```
registrationdate
2022-01-31
2021-12-01
2022-07-01
2021-11-12
2021-10-10
2022-01-07 
2020-08-26
```

if I select month 12 and year 2021 I need only previous data of December 2021

$month=12 and $year =2021

```
$selectedmonthMalestudents  = \DB::table('students')
                   
        ->whereRaw('extract(month from registrationdate) = ?','<' [$month])
        ->whereRaw('extract(year from registrationdate) = ?', [$year])
        ->count();
```

Please Help me How to do these...

Answer (score 1):

All you need to call the `whereMonth` and `whereYear` method of eloquent. I have doubts whether that can work with DB::table but you can use the model anyway.

```
$selectedmonthMalestudents  = \DB::table('students')
->whereMonth('salary_date', $month)
->whereYear('salary_date', $year)
->count();
```

***personal suggestions:-*** always use model instead of DB::table();

Answer (score 0):

> First of all you should never use a Raw SQL statement in laravel, well except in some scenarios which it is absolutely necessary, because of [security issues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGGVGiq2y8&t=774s)

so in your controller, you can use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/)

```
public function index(Students $student) {
  $date = Carbon::parse(' Decemeber of 2021 ');
  $result = $student->where('registrationdate', '<', $date)->get();

  return response()->json([compact('result'), 200]);
}
```

or use Laravel's Eloquent ORM Map collection method like

```
public function index(Students $student) {
  $date = Carbon::parse(' Decemeber of 2021 ');
  $result = $student->filter(function($std, $key) {
     $created_at = Carbon::now($std['registration_date']);
     if($create_at->isBefore($date)) {
       return true;
     }
   })->get();

  return response()->json([compact('result'), 200]);
}
```